# Not beign able to map fetched data from a Redux createAsyncThunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

im using 'create async thunk' this way =>

```
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import movieApi from '../common/API\'s/movieApi'
import { apiKey } from '../common/API\'s/MovieApiKey'
import { HTTP_STATUS } from '../App/constants' 
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchMovieData = createAsyncThunk(
    'movieGrid/fetchMovieData', //1ero => string 'name/f(x)Name'
    async () => { //Una f(x) que retorne una promesa => async f(x) => SIEMPRE retornan Promises 
        const response = await movieApi.get(
            `?apiKey=${apiKey}&s=batman&type=movie`
        ) 
        const definiteResponse = response.data.Search
        return definiteResponse
       
    
    }
)

const movieGridSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'movieGrid',
    initialState:{
        movies:[],
        loading:null,
        data:null
    },
    reducers:{

    },
    extraReducers:{
        [fetchMovieData.pending](state, action){
            state.loading = HTTP_STATUS.PENDING
    },
    [fetchMovieData.fulfilled](state,action){
         state.loading = HTTP_STATUS.FULFILLED
         state.data = action.payload
    },
    [fetchMovieData.rejected](state, action){
        state.loading = HTTP_STATUS.REJECTED

},
    }
},)

export default movieGridSlice.reducer
```

in a Slice called movies, the basic idea of it is grab 20 movies that comes in an array.
The thing is that im able to see the data displays an Array(20) called "Results" (i leave an image behind) But when i enter usind "dot notation" just to map the array it throws me this error => TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')
Im really lost bout it, any help wil be really appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: @skyboyer Thxz for the dit bro!

Comment: can you post the code of calling fetchMovieData and map? @skyboyer